# fetch Input text value using Java script from p:dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am new to java script .
I try to get value from p:dialog using java script but i can't get the value, I post my code below , This is use for front-end validation. help me to solve this problem.

```
home.xhtml
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<f:view contentType="text/html" locale="en">
 <pe:head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>

         <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/css.css" ></link> 

<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="../../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" />
<script>
function myvalidation(obj){
var bla = document.getElementById(obj).value
alert("hai"+bla)//hai undefined
}
 function myvalidation1(){
var bla = $('#obj').val();
alert("hai1"+bla)//hai undefined
}
</script>

</pe:head>
```

```
        <pe:layout fullPage="true">

                         <pe:layoutPane position="north" closable="false" resizable="false" size="14%">
                            <h:form>
                                                        <p:graphicImage value="/images/header.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"></p:graphicImage>

                        </h:form>

                         </pe:layoutPane>

                         <pe:layoutPane header="Dashboard" position="west" size="20%"  resizable="true">
                          <f:facet name="header">  
                    Main Menu  
                </f:facet>  
                            <h:form>
                                <ui:include src="../../menu.xhtml" />

                            </h:form>
                        </pe:layoutPane>


                         <pe:layoutPane  position="center" size="80%" resizable="true" id="centerIDContent" closable="false">
                            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="center_content">
                                <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
                            </h:form>

                        </pe:layoutPane>


        </pe:layout>
   </h:body>
   </f:view>
   </ui:composition>
```

below mentioning code(home1.xhtml) in that i use two dialog box

```
home1.xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   template="../../pages/xhtml/home.xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
 xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

       <ui:define name="content">

       <p:commandLink styleClass="image-align" action="#{FormMB.loadDialogBox}" update=":center_content:dialogPanel"  oncomplete="PF('Dialog').show();">
 <p:graphicImage value="/images/registration.jpg"></p:graphicImage>
         </p:commandLink>
              <p:commandLink styleClass="image-align"  action="#{FormMB.loadDialogBox1}" update=":center_content:dialogPanel1"  oncomplete="PF('Dialog1').show();">
<p:graphicImage value="/images/view.jpg"></p:graphicImage>
         </p:commandLink>



             <p:dialog  header="Registration" id="dlg" appendTo="@(body)"  widgetVar="Dialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" width="75%" resizable="false" visible="#{FormMB.vendorFlag}">
             <p:outputPanel id="dialogPanel">
            <h:form id="ven">

            <p:panelGrid columns="5" style="text-align:left" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-3,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-3" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
            <h:outputText  class="label_ui" value="Firm Name " for="vfname"/>
            <p:inputText   value="#{FormMB.number}"   id="vfname" styleClass="inputTxt" onblur="myvalidation('center_content:dialogPanel:vfname')">
            <p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this" immediate="true" update="@all"></p:ajax>
            </p:inputText>

            </p:panelGrid>
            <br></br>
            <center><p:commandButton value="Submit" process="@this" immediate="true" action="#{FormMB.Register}" oncomplete="PF('Dialog').hide();" ></p:commandButton>

            </center>
            </h:form>
            </p:outputPanel>

            </p:dialog>
           <p:dialog  header="Registration" id="dlg" appendTo="@(body)"  widgetVar="Dialog1" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" width="75%" resizable="false" visible="#{FormMB.vendorFlag}">
             <p:outputPanel id="dialogPanel1">
            <h:form id="ven">

            <p:panelGrid columns="5" style="text-align:left" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-3,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-3" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
            <h:outputText  class="label_ui" value="Firm Name " for="vfname"/>
            <p:inputText   value="#{FormMB.number}"   id="vfname" styleClass="inputTxt" onblur="onblur="myvalidation1()">
            <p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this" immediate="true" update="@all"></p:ajax>
            </p:inputText>

            </p:panelGrid>
            <br></br>
            <center><p:commandButton value="Submit" process="@this" immediate="true" action="#{FormMB.Register}" oncomplete="PF('Dialog1').hide();" ></p:commandButton>

            </center>
            </h:form>
            </p:outputPanel>

            </p:dialog>

 </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
```

In that i use both jquery and java-script but both giving same error (undefined).

Comment: When and from where are you calling myValidation(obj)? 

I ask because I don't see where the argument obj is coming from and am guessing that it results in undefined.

Comment: (onblur="myvalidation('center_content:dialogPanel:vfname')" ) passed through this , i got undefined .. help me to get the input text value from dialog box.

Comment: What does console.log(obj) after you .getElementById say?